# Local Commits after merging

Tags: git, git-merge, git-push, git-pull, feature-branch

I was working on a feature branch (let's call it DEV-1234), not yet made any changes, came back to work after a few days break and of course the develop branch had a huge amount of changes in it which I wanted to merge to my feature branch so as to start working with the latest version of the code.

So, I did this:

```
git checkout develop
git pull 
git checkout feature/DEV-1234
git merge develop
```

Now, as I check git status on that branch, I get this:

```
$ git status
On branch feature/DEV-1234
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature/DEV-1234' by 503 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

I don't have any local commits though. Or does that merge count as a local commit? What actually happens if I make `git push` in this branch as it suggests?

Comment: Hint: pull is not fetch.

Comment: @matt I actually tried fetching on both branches after seeing that message, but the situation remains the same. My develop is up to date with origin/develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you now push your branch, you'll update the remote version of the branch, who currently has the ref *before* the merge with the newest commits.

It's not necessary, though, you might as well work on it for now and push only when you deem it ready for the pull request.

Initial state :

```
A---B <<< develop, feature-branch, origin/feature-branch
     \
      C--(snip 510 commis)--D <<< origin/develop
```

After you pulled develop :

```
A---B <<< feature-branch, origin/feature-branch
     \
      C--(snip 510 commis)--D <<< develop, origin/develop
```

After you merged it `into feature-branch` :

```
      origin/feature-branch
     /
A---B-------------------------E <<< feature-branch
     \                       /
      C--(snip 510 commis)--D <<< develop, origin/develop
```

and finally when you'll have pushed :

```
A---B-------------------------E <<< feature-branch, origin/feature-branch
     \                       /
      C--(snip 510 commis)--D <<< develop, origin/develop
```

Comment: Yeah so basically that amount of commits is included in that "merge" commit which just show as a "merge develop to feature/... " including that heck-ton of changes in it in the repository?

Comment: Yes, in a way. They're not really "included" in that merge, but since E makes that long list of commits reachable, it's a good enough metaphor.